# Meteor Up - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.100.12:

Tags: meteor, meteor-up, mup

I have a Meteor App based on Angular 1.3 + Meteor 1.5.2.2.
I am using Ubuntu 17.
I am trying to deploy my Meteor App on local machine first before going for live server using Meteor Up.
But I am facing this issue when running `mup setup` command

```
martinihenry@martinihenry:~/mytestapp-prod/.deploy$ mup setup

Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[192.168.100.12] - Setup Docker
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.100.12:22
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1078:14)
```

Here is my mup.json:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: '192.168.100.12',
      username: 'root',
      // pem: './path/to/pem'
      // password: 'server-password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'mytestapp-prod',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: '192.168.100.12:3000',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },

    // ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
    //   autogenerate: {
    //     email: 'email.address@domain.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
    //     domains: 'website.com,www.website.com'
    //   }
    // },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is using Meteor 1.3 or older
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have sshd running on your machine, or you have not enabled remote ssh access for root.

You need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and comment out the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Just below it, add the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then restart SSH:

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: `service ssh restart` says: `Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device`

Comment: 216 GB/251 GB available

Comment: What about the partitions? Is one of them full `df -h`

Comment: there are no partitions, single disk & drive

Comment: It is still possible to run out of disk space. For example if you have lots of small files, it can run out of inodes. Have a look at this article for details https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html

Comment: Another alternative is to check if you can manually ssh to your own machine, start with doing it as your own user, and then with root, which will probably fail.

Comment: I restarted my local machine, it solved the above issue, but now when I run mup setup, it says: Setup Docker and then it does nothing

Comment: @StormTrooper Did you find further solution? As I am also trying to deploy it on my own machine and got stuck here.

Comment: What are the errors you get? It strikes me that trying to deploy to your own machine is a waste of time, especially as it is not proving to be easy. Why not just spin up a remote instance on AWS Lightsail if you want to try it? It is remarkably easy to do, and your desktop machine is polluted with all your dev setup, so it really isn't a realistic operation to do anyway.

Comment: @Mikkel Thanks for your quick reply. I will surely check that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but this a known and reproducable bug resulting from inotfiy-watch using all of the available slots for watches, and while very misleading, it actually has absolutely nothing to do with disk space.

The easy fix? increase watch slots:

```
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```